# Element is not clickable at point (1254, 21). Other element would receive the click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**I am using protractor and selenium server with angularJS for UI testing,**

This is my TestCase:

```
it('Click on Top Headings one by one', function () {        
    //click on Top Heading one by one
    ptor.element.all(by.repeater('application in workbenchOptions.applications')).then(function (arrs) {
        ptor.sleep(3000);
        arrs[2].click();
        ptor.sleep(3000);
        arrs[3].click();
        ptor.sleep(3000);
        arrs[1].click();
        ptor.sleep(3000);
        arrs[2].click();
        ptor.sleep(3000);
        arrs[0].click();
        ptor.sleep(2000);
    });
});
```

This is my UI where I am trying to click each heading one by one

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVE9K.png]

First of all I am clicking on `arrs[2]` i.e. Clientside Test Case

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRE2s.png]

then I am clicking on `arrs[3]`, `arrs[1]`, `arrs[2]`, `arrs[0]` , everything is clicking , but if in the beginning suppose `arrs[0]` is already open then I am not able to click on this again and I got a error message

```
UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1254, 21). 
Other element would receive the click: 
<div class="slider-wrapper pl-pageslide-wrapper" style="transition: width 0.3s, height; -webkit-transition: width 0.3s, height; z-index: 1000; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: auto; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);">...</div>
```

I tested against both Chrome and Firefox and the same error occurs

Comment: I have re-checked my case and found, Now Every Heading is clickable, but still getting this message

error: Element is not clickable at point (1254, 21). Other element would receive the click: <div class="slider-wrapper pl-pageslide-wrapper">...

and when i am checking class slider-wrapper through inspect element , I am finding that this class covers complete UI

and I have one other issue within the same, suppose previously my Top Heading opened is AshuTests and I am expecting this,

then this gives me this error

Expected 'AshuTests
ExcelImport
UploadTest
MarketPlaceTest' to be 'AshuTests'

Comment: Have you tried to disable your transitions?

Comment: are you saying to disable or comment out this class, class="slider-wrapper, if yes, then this is not possible, because by this all my work get disturbed, is there any other way, so that other things remain as it is?

Comment: The error message is suggesting that the element is not clickable from a user point of view. Is there any other element upon it, with a higher `z-index` maybe?

Comment: every element is clicking, but still I am getting this error message, from error message i am getting  class="slider-wrapper also receive the click, which is bounded to complete body, is it possible that i can remove this effect from this class??

Comment: Something seems wrong with your event listeners implementation. You might need to change it...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with elements without a fixed position. I used the following code in protractor:

```
var el = ...; // some protractor element
el.getLocation().then(function(location) {
  browser.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0," + (location.y - 70)+ ")");
  el.click();
});
```

Note: I also use an offset of -70px because the page has a menu fixed at the top of the page. Without the offset, elements get scrolled behind the menu and the message "Element is not clickable..." is displayed again.

Answer (score 1):

i think is this helpful to you:

```
ptor.executeScript('window.scrollTo(1254,21);').then(function() {
        element(by.<<here your button locator>>).click();
    })
```

your webdriver is unable to read that point (1254,21),the reason is your protractor browser unable to cover the full of page what do you want to test, then we give a command that browser is scroll to that point (1254,21), then perform the click operation

Comment: Add an explanation why you think this code may be a solution for the problem.

Comment: Regardless of that, you MUST provide an explanation otherwise your answer may be marked for deletion. An "answer" is differentiated from a "comment" by the detailed explanation it provides.

Comment: k; your webdriver is unable to read that point (1254,21),the reason is your protractor browser unable to cover the full of page what do you want to test, then we give a command that browser is scroll to that point (1254,21), then perform the click operation.

Comment: Please add this to the answer. Click Edit on your answer and add this there.

Comment: this is not adequete solution, how i can check where i have to scroll the browser to do my work

Comment: if u get on error on click an element, u can get pixel points on error message.